# Is there any way to use socket in a World Of Warcraft Lua script?

Tags: sockets, lua, world-of-warcraft

I've tried to use: `require("socket")`, but I red on forums about WoW that I can't use the `require` command. Is there any other way to accomplish this? I'd like to pass data from the Lua thread to a Java thread.

Comment: AFAIK WoW sandboxes its Lua VM specifically to prevent exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: you cant use non lua code nor can access the internet or any thing outside the game world

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot use sockets, and there are no other way to communicate with other programs either. This is a restriction applied by Blizzard to prevent some forms of cheating, and to avoid malware propagation and other account security breaches.

In general you won't be able to communicate with third-party apps. There are workarounds, but they are hacks, they are likely to break in future updates of WoW, and they probably violate some terms of service.

Comment: The best way to communicate data to an external process is to write it to the Saved Variables and then read the saved .lua file. However this information is refreshed only when the game GUI is reloaded and there is no way of accessing information in real time.